# Remove <br /> tags which are unwanted/invalid children of a <ul> tag

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, str-replace, removechild

How can I remove these `<br />` tags from between the `<ul>` tags?

```
<p>Paragraph 1 <br /> Break line</p>
     <ul> <br />
    <li>  New Line</li>   <br />
    <li> Second line </li>   <br />
    <li> Third line </li>   <br />
    </ul>  
<p>Paragraph two. <br /> break line</p>
```

The `<br />` tags between list items are adding lines between list items.

How can I remove these `<br />` tags in between `<ul> </ul>` only?  I don't want any other `<br/>` tags to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use regex to parse HTML because it doesn't know the difference between tags and text that looks like tags.

It may look like more code, but it is code that will be more reliable, easier to read, and easier to maintain.

The XPath query says: "target all br tags that are the direct children of ul and the ul tags can be found in any depth of the document.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PnsEs)) ([Even allows `<br>` in the `<li>`](https://3v4l.org/6VWWS))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div>
<p>Paragraph 1 <br /> Break line</p>
     <ul> <br />
    <li>  New Line</li>   <br />
    <li> Second line </li>   <br />
    <li> Third line </li>   <br />
    </ul>  
<p>Paragraph two. <br /> break line</p>
</div>
HTML;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//ul/br') as $br) {
    $br->parentNode->removeChild($br);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<div>
<p>Paragraph 1 <br> Break line</p>
     <ul> 
    <li>  New Line</li>   
    <li> Second line </li>   
    <li> Third line </li>   
    </ul>  
<p>Paragraph two. <br> break line</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It works well, But the text are returned unreadable text instead of the stored text, and the text is not in English language it is local language. and it was displaying good but after I have tried with your code the text are returned to some unreadable text.

Comment: It is important that the [mcve] in your question is realistic.  This prevents volunteers wasting their time fixing something that was not exposed in the original question.  Please edit your question to provide a better sample HTML document.

Comment: I already have got great Answer to my question, it is a real question, But posted it for its specific side, Now I have got answer from @Barmar And that's it Thank you.

Comment: Well, I've stated why you should not use regex.  If you improve your question, I'll improve my answer.  It isn't hard to add your local language content to your sample text.  It is unfair to tell me that my professional answer does not work, then withhold the cases when it breaks for you.

Comment: I didn't say your answer not work, in fact see the first word in my answer to your code, It says "It works well", and your Answer is professionally Great, But one thing I noticed it is that my local language has been changed only.  Thank you for your Great answer once again.

Comment: I didn't say your answer not work, in fact see the first word in my answer to your code, It says "It works well", and your Answer is professionally Great, But one thing I noticed it is that my local language has been changed only.  Thank you for your Great answer once again.

Comment: It is very simple for you to type a few words from your local language into your question's sample string.  It would take you less time than typing comments to me.  I don't understand your resistance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_replace_callback()` to replace everything between `<ul>` and `</ul>`, using a callback function that removes `<br />`

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('#<ul>.*?</ul>#s', function($matches) {
    return str_replace('<br />', '', $matches[0]);
}, $text);
```

Comment: As a fringe case consideration, this approach will incorrectly remove `<br />` tags that are children of `<li>` tags.

Comment: Thank you, but it returns `PHP Warning:  preg_replace_callback(): Unknown modifier 'l'`

Comment: I forgot to escape the embedded `/` or use a different delimiter.